# Can a print a formated array to a file using php?

Tags: php, arrays, fopen, fwrite

I know I can print an array using `print_r()` function in PHP like this

```
print_r($array);
```

And to make it look pretty in the browser, I can wrap it up with the HTML `<pre>` block like this

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($array);
echo '</pre>';
```

But, how can I write the second nice output to a file not to a browser using HTML?

Here is what I have tried

```
$file = fopen('test.log', 'a+');
fwrite($file, print_r($this->header, TRUE) . PHP_EOL);
fclose($file);
```

But, that does not write the array's content nicely in the test.log file. it writes it as a data dump which is hard to read.

How can I nicely print the array content for easy read

Comment: have you tried  using a foreach?

Comment: Replace each space between `newline` and first alphanumerical character with `\t` (tabulator). This should create nice indents.

Answer (score 2):

I found 2 way to do this. the first one, the credit goes to  Md. Khairul Islam

this method will use a foreach to write the array content to the file

```
private function fwriteArray($result, $file){

    if( !is_array($result) && !is_object($result)) {    
            return false;
    }

    foreach($result as $k => $v){
        if(is_array($v) || is_object($v) ){

            $this->fwriteArray($v, $file);

        } else {
            fwrite($file, '    [' . $k.'] => ' .  $v . PHP_EOL);
        }
    }
}
```

second method is to convert the array to json string and use JSON_PRETTY_PRINT to print the data nicely

```
fwrite($file, PHP_EOL . str_replace("\n", PHP_EOL, json_encode( $myArray, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code. I do not know what $this->header is working inside your webapp. But assuming its a array . the following example works file for single array .

```
 $text="";
 $file = fopen('test.log', 'a+');
 foreach($this->header as $key=>$val)
  {
  $text.="$key=>$val \n\r";
  }
fwrite($file, $text);
fclose($file);
```

Comment: I won't format it nicely, which is key problem for author.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [output control](http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php).

```
ob_start();
print_r($array);
$content = ob_get_clean();

$file = fopen('test.log', 'a+');
fwrite($file, $content . PHP_EOL);
fclose($file);
```